# Lightning List Dual Box

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

Selected Options in Lightning Dual ListBox are automatically sorted alphabetically.How to disable this.can anyone please explain

[image]

Comment: I've tried the example code from [Dual Listbox documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-dual-listbox/example) and can see the selections are NOT automatically sorted alphabetically. What is the apiVersion of your code?

Comment: After the selections are saved.When we try to retrieve them the values ,they are returned in alphabetical order.

Comment: i think you are getting values in alphabetic order.
Or you can paste your code

Comment: Yes Im getting values in alphabetical order.How to stop the values to from being sorted in alphabetical order

Comment: Sharing the code for reference
Html Code
`<lightning-dual-listbox name="Types" label="Select Types" source-label="Available Types"
                  selected-label="Selected RecordTypes" field-level-help="Select RTypes in Order of Priority" options={defaultAvailableObjects}
                  value={selectedObjects}
                  onchange={handleObjectChange} required></lightning-dual-listbox>`
Javascript Code

Comment: Javascript code
`handleObjectChange(e){
     this.selectedObjects= e.detail.value;
     }`
After saving  values using lightning-record-edit-from when I try to retrieve the values are not in the order I saved

Comment: @Swetha The api version of code is 55